# IE6 the last three characters in a div are being repeated else where in the page? really weird

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, character, repeat

Hey, Basically i have an issues (in IE6) where the last three characters of a line of text in a div are being repeated further down the page even though they are only in the HTML once.

http://www.disturbmedia.com/jason/test/
please see the numbers in black, its always the last three characters that get repeated, so strange.

I have never seen this before, its only in IE6? Anyone have any info?!
Am super confused as to how this is happening.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: I've had this one before, it was due to an unclosed `<b>` tag.

Comment: @Raveren: I wouldn't be surprised if IE6 had problems with unclosed `<b>` tags, but the example provided by the OP contains no such tags.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I am posting a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

IE6 had this strange bug involving multiple floated elements; text characters from the last of the floated elements are sometimes duplicated below the last float.

You may want to check the following article for further reading, fixes and possible workarounds:

- [Explorer 6 Duplicate Characters Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/dup-characters.html)

---

The bug can be replicated with the following HTML:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<div style="float:left">
</div>

<div style="float:left">
</div>

<!-- Both comments must be here for bug -->
<!-- Both comments must be here for bug -->

<div style="float:left; width:100%">
Repeated characters
</div>

</body></html>
```

Source: [Suspected bug in IE6, unwanted repeated characters](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/9261.htm)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, interesting stuff ... will try and find a work around, the link you posted is a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes due to comments in HTML.